# Cordova BLE Central Plugin - Bluetooth Prompt Not Dismissing on Android 11 and Above

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor-plugin

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of the Cordova BLE Central Plugin to manage Bluetooth functionality. The Bluetooth functionality works seamlessly on Android versions up to 11. However, starting from Android 11, although the Bluetooth gets enabled successfully, the prompt requesting Bluetooth activation persists, preventing the seamless operation of the application.

Issue Details:
The Cordova BLE Central Plugin is used for Bluetooth management in the project.
Bluetooth functionality works well on Android versions up to 11.
On Android 11 and above, Bluetooth gets enabled, but the prompt for enabling Bluetooth does not dismiss.
This behavior interrupts the seamless operation of the application.

Additional Information:
Cordova Version: 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Cordova BLE Central Plugin Version: ^1.7.2-slim
Android Version: 12 and Above
Relevant Code Snippets: Included

Steps Taken:
I have verified that the Cordova BLE Central Plugin is up to date.
I have checked for any relevant updates or issues on the plugin's GitHub repository.

Note:
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into potential solutions or workarounds, your assistance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Expected Behavior:
Bluetooth should be enabled without any persistent prompts on Android 11 and above, similar to the behavior observed on previous Android versions.

Comment: Your description was quite alright but I guess there is code of some kind involved. Please share the interesting parts of the code. Do not just paste what you have, but instead take care to show what people can read and have opnions about.